# Manage source and javadoc for Grails automatic dependencies in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: grails, maven, intellij-idea, javadoc

How do I attach source and javadoc to libraries in IntelliJ IDEA that are linked automatically by Grails dependency resolution and are not explicitly listed in the IDEA project settings?

For example in
**BuildConfig.groovy**:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    repositories {
        mavenRepo "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
    }
    dependencies {
        runtime 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:0.17.7'
    }
}
```

Is there a method to have IDEA automatically pick up the source and javadoc from the Maven repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDEA attached the source automatically to the project plugin module.  The JavaDoc can be manually attached to the plugin module in the project structure interface at:

File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Modules -> *project name*-grailsPlugins -> Paths -> JavaDoc

[image: IDEA project structure]

Answer (score 1):

not an answer, but an idea:

you might hook into the `'grails integrate-with'` gant script and add this functionality yourself.  `$GRAILS_HOME/scripts/IntegrateWith.groovy` uses some templates for `.ipr` and `.iml` file that could be modified.

At some point in future it is excepted that gradle will be used for building Grails projects but there's still a long way to go.

Answer (score 1):

IDEA 11 will be ably to search and download sources for any jar. 
The search is performed using https://oss.sonatype.org/ by artifactId and version got from name of jar.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I found that IDEA 10.5.2 did in fact attach the sources automatically from the grails dependencies but not the javadoc.

Comment: Any info on _how to do this_?