# Error 404 while looking maven-downloaded javadoc with External Documentation in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javadoc

I have attached some maven library to my project. It has javadoc with it and the file is present

[image]

Unfortunately, when I am trying to invoke external documentation on any of this library classes, I am getting 404 error:

[image]

Note, that actual location of JAR file is apparently different: file is located where local repository is located, while it is referred to as located inside project tree.

**UPDATE**

If I invoke the quick documentation for the same class, it shows. Probably, it generates content from code comments. Simultaneously, it displays some sort of warning above:

> Following external urls were checked:
>   http://localhost:63342/MYPROJECTPATH/commons-lang3-3.4-javadoc.jar/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html
>   The documentation for this element is not found. Please add all the
>   needed paths to API docs in Project Settings.

Comment: Is this only happening for JUnit v4.11? If so, I suspect there is an issue with that javadoc JAR. I recommend checking it's SHA1 hash value against the expect value, `f3289e8097c0013b711d058b563064c3bded4423` shown at [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|junit|junit|4.11|jar). (In Windows, [HashTab](http://implbits.com/products/hashtab/) is a handy way to check Hash sums). If there is an issue with it, delete it from your repository so it gets a fresh downloaded.

Comment: It is happening for any library, controlled by Maven (apparently)

Comment: Are the javadocs displaying OK in IDEA's documentation window? (if not, likely an issue with the JAR file; if so, likely issue with built-in web server) I noticed two of the directories in the path to the JAR file start with `!`. It's _possible_ that is causing an issue since `!` is used in a file URL to indicate then something is inside an archive file. For example: `jar:file:/D:/dev/foo-library.jar!/data/Configuration-Resource.txt`. Also take a look in the IDEA logs (_Help > Show Logs_) to see if there is any indication as to the problem.

Comment: What is "IDEA documentation window"? Quick documentation?

Comment: Yes, the Quick Documentation Window.

Comment: @MarkVedder see my update about quick doc window, please...

Comment: Assuming you've ruled out that the `!` in your path is not causing the issue, the only other thing I can recommend trying is to invalidate your caches/indexes (_File > Invalidate Cache_) and then restart IDEA. Let it re-index your project and then give the external doc a try. If that fails to work, I recommend contacting JetBrains support.