# How to make IDEA show more detailed doc when coding with spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, documentation

Is there a way to let the idea show more detailed documentation of spring boot like what it does to Java SE classes?

[image: IDEA showing the LocalDateTime doc]

[image: IDEA showing the @Data doc (Can it be more detailed?)]

Comment: Try to download docs (check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072667/how-to-force-intellij-to-download-javadocs-with-maven)  or add docs manually into Project Structure for Spring docs.spring.io\spring\docs\current\javadoc-api\

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.

Comment: I guess screenshots are fine in this case as it is about how IntelliJ displays javadocs and it is not an image of code/an error message.